# What will be the optimized version of this code block

Tags: python

```
cnt = 0
N = int(raw_input())
for i in range(1,N+1):
    for j in range(1,N+1):
        for k in range(1,N+1):
            if (i*j)%k == 0:
                cnt+=1
```

Given python code , can it be optimized further such that cnt value is correct . One approach which i have tried was to count factor in kth loop which will make complexity from o(n^3) to o(n^2root(n))

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you can do to improve this.
The algorithm counts how many (`i, j`) products are divisible by `k`, with all numbers in the range `[1, N]`.  You can reduce overhead with judicious choice of loop limits:

```
for i in range(1, N+1):
    for j in range(i, N+1):
        for k in range(i*j, N+1):
            if (i*j) % k == 0:
                cnt += 1
```

For `k` to divide `i*j`, `i` and `j` must contain each prime factor of `k` in the requisite quantity.  You can compute these directly, rather than iterating through all possibilities.  Start with `k` in the outer loop, determine its prime factors, and then *generate* all of the `i*j` combinations that will cover those factors.

Start with a loop to generate the prime factorization for the entire range [2,N].  Approach it live the sieve of Eratosthenes, but instead of disqualifying a composite number immediately, instead keep a list of its factors.  For instance, if N=10, you will finish this loop with a handy list of factorization:

```
 2   2
 3   3
 4   2 2
 5   5
 6   2 3
 7   7
 8   2 2 2
 9   3 3
10   2 5
```

Now you have the factorization of every `i j k` value you want.

```
for k in range(2, N):
    fact = # prime factors of k
    for i in range(2, N):
        if i has no factors in common with k:
            count += N // i  # We need j%k == 0; this is a simple division.
        else:
            divisors = # remove common i-factors from k-factors (reduce)
            new_i = # product of remaining factors
            count += N // new_i   # j must be a multiple of "reduced" k
```

For instance, for `k=6`, we iterate like this:

```
i = 1: relatively prime to k; add (10 // 6) j-values: j=6 is the only solution
i = 2: Common factor of 2; treat as k = 6/2; add (10 // 3) j-values
i = 3: Common factor of 3; treat as k = 6/3; add (10 // 2) j-values
i = 4: Common factor of 2; treat as k = 6/2; add (10 // 3) j-values
i = 5: relatively prime to k; add (10 // 6) j-values: j=6 is the only solution
```

Do you see how that works?

You can make a few additional checks to reduce the overhead by a linear and sub-linear factors, but we'll still have a controlling **O(n^2)** loop as above.